# IE protection warning clears my textbox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, textbox

I have a problem with the internet security warning.
I've written a download script. If i type a special string into a textbox, i can download a file, but the protection of the ie makes some trouble. My problem is when i allow it, the value of the textbox disappears. I just want to let the string in there. Any ideas how to do that?
Downloadscript: Just changes the location to the file.
IE Version: 8
IE message

> To help protect your security, Internet Explorer blocked this site
>   from downloading files to your computer. Click here for options...

Comment: Can you be specific about what exactly happens? What warning appears?

Comment: What's the problem (error details)? What version of IE? How is your 'download script' supposed to work?

Comment: Is your input box part of an HTML form?

Comment: See updated question, i adde some details. Thanks for your help.